# call a procedure with date parameter in sqlplus oracle using shell script

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, sqlplus

I want to call a procedure in sqlplus oracle using shell script,
my procedure name is `getdate_proc` with two parameters, startdate and enddate.
I want to set `startdate = sysdate` and `enddate = sysdate + 5 days`

```
for example :execute getdate_proc(to_date('05/05/2015', 'MM-DD-YYYY'),to_date('05/09/2015','MM-DD-YYYY'))
```

below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
sqlplus -s /nolog << EOF
connect scott/tiger
--execute procedure with parameter
execute getdate_proc(to_date(sysdate, 'MM-DD-YYYY'),to_date(sysdate + 5days,'MM-DD-YYYY'))
--set spooling to save in csv
set underline off
SET RECSEP OFF
set verify off
set colsep ','
set linesize 300
set trimspool on
spool /home/user/project/samp.csv
select * from att2;
spool off
set verify off
```

Answer (score 2):

i solved my problem with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
date1='date'
date1=$(/bin/date --date="$date1" -d "+0 day" +"%F")
date2=$(/bin/date --date="$date1" -d "+4 day" +"%F")
echo $date1
echo $date2
sqlplus -s /nolog << EOF
connect scott/tiger
--execute procedure with parameter
execute attendance(to_date('$date1', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('$date2','YYYY-MM-DD'))
--set spooling to save in csv
set underline off
SET RECSEP OFF
set verify off
set colsep ','
set linesize 300
set trimspool on
spool /home/user/project/samp.csv
select * from att2;
spool off
set verify off
```

:) cheers